# Codeigniter Insert with Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there a way to make this Query work in MySQL Codeigniter

Basically is make a select inside a Insert to avoid double Query

I want to make an INSERT a row in a table called **recibos_nomina** but the field **recibos_nomina.id_usuario** is one a table called **usuarios**  i have **usuarios.rfc** and i want to nest **SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE rfc = XXX** to get the id and insert  in **recibos_nomina.id_usuario** with one Query only, this is possible with MySQL but i don't know how to make it with codeigniter.

---

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->query('insert into recibos_nomina(id_empresa, id_usuario, fecha, folio, total, uuid, url_xml, temporal, folio_fiscal, fechahora_certificado, csd_sat, sello_cfd, sello_sat, sello)
    values(?, (SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE rfc = ?), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array(
                            2,
                            //intval($this->post('id_empleado')),
                            $recibo->usuario->rfc,
                            date("Y-m-d"),
                            $recibo->folio,
                            $recibo->total,
                            $recibo->uuid,
                            $recibo->url_xml,
                            1,
                            $recibo->uuid,
                            //str_replace("T", " ", $recibo->fecha),
                            $recibo->fecha,
                            $recibo->csd_sat,
                            $recibo->sello_cfd,
                            $recibo->sello_sat,
                            $recibo->sello_cfd
                        ));
                        $id_recibo = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: your query or may be questioned is unclear can you please edit it.  I can help you over this but first, need to get the question correctly

Comment: I want to make an INSERT a row in a table called recibos_nomina but the field recibos_nomina.id_usuario is one a table called usuarios i have usuarios.rfc and i want to nest SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE rfc = XXX to get the id and insert in recibos_nomina.id_usuario with one Query only, this is possible with MySQL but i don't know how to make it with codeigniter.